# Trying to change the frame of UIView in swift whilst the app is running?

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the frame of a UIView when the orientation of my device is changed but nothing appears to work.  Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    guard
        let portraitScreenView = viewScreenSizePortrait,
        let overLay = overLayView else{return}

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait{
        print("isPortrait")
        overLay.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: portraitScreenView.width, height: portraitScreenView.height)
        self.overLayView.frame = overLay.frame
    }else{
        print("isLandscape")
        overLay.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: portraitScreenView.height, height: portraitScreenView.width)
        self.overLayView.frame = overLay.frame
    }

    print("self.overLayView.frame: \(self.overLayView.frame)")


}
```

Comment: call function self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Or try to change the frame on main queue:  DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // UI changes
    }

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.setNeedsDisplay()` after your frame change.

Comment: self? Just the UIview or self (UIViewController)?

Comment: I tried against the specific UIView and the whole view but it did not work